# Xcode project can't be opened

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried to rename my project in Xcode and messed up all the files so now when I open the project it looks like on the screenshot below. What can I do to make my project open normally again?

[image]

Comment: Put back a backup maybe?

Comment: I don't have a backup..

Comment: How you open this project in XCode? By double clicking the **ProjectName.xcworkspace** or any other thing?

Comment: Yes, I open it by double clicking xcworkspace file

Comment: when you se you renamed it in Xcode, what does that mean? If your project name is different than what you started it as.. locate your folder where the project sits and rename the workspace back to the original name

Comment: It looks like Xcode thinks that it's folder rather than `.xcodeproj`, can you try to add that extension and tell us what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make new project with the new name and then copy the file into it and init pods then install all your pods on the new project

Comment: I tried to copy main.storyboard to the new project but it doesn't appear in the Xcode